# VPN Client using WFP

Tags: vpn, wfp

I am exploring possibility of creating a VPN client for Wireguard using WFP framework. I see many example of VPN client developed using NDIS library. I am interested doing the same using WFP. But i am not sure of the possibility and couldn't find any sample code using WFP. Could you please give some clear direction.

Comment: You should also edit the tags to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You want to to create VPN client. It's the first part of your question or task.

The second is - you want to use WPF as a GUI.

It's possible. For sure :)

To give you more information in our answers you should also ask you question with more information in it.

At the end it can be more than 1 question from your side. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour and examples of good questions.

Comment: I am not asking about WPF. Asking about WFP (Windows Filtering Platform). I will correct the subject and content.

Comment: @Alex, it was a WPF tag in your question. Now it's edited, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to encapsulate packets or modify headers on the VPN Clinet side, this is possible at the WFP layer. In addition, the burdensome tasks of handling at the NDIS layer can be easily handled at the TCP layer.
However, it is difficult to verify that the mechanism for re-injecting the packet, which is a feature of WFP, works well.

And in my experience, performance is skeptical.